# Vite: Replace env vars at build time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I am using Vue + Vite + TS and I am building a few libraries that I would like to build and import somewhere else.

The point is that I set some environment variables using the dotenv, hence I can use things like import.meta.env.MY_VARIABLE.

But they are being availed during the run time of the place I run them, hence the env files need to be placed in the component that requires those libs.

I would like to know if there is way so they get replaced in the build time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want to use the ***define*** option.

```
let commonConfig =
{

  plugins: [vue()],

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url))     
    },
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        nested: resolve(__dirname, 'auth_redirect.html')
      }
    }
  }
}

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode, ssrBuild }) => {
  
  if (command === 'serve')
  {
//
    return commonConfig;

  } 
  else 
  {
    commonConfig.define = {
      "BUILD_TIMESTAMP": new Date().toISOString()
      
    };

    // command === 'build'
    return commonConfig;
  }
})
```

And then you can just assign BUILD_TIMESTAMP to any javascript variable in your appCode.

`const buildNum = "BUILD_TIMESTAMP";//You will get right val in this`.

define has to be compatible with https://esbuild.github.io/api/#non-analyzable-imports so gives issues in serve mode. So I have used it conditionally in build mode only.
In Dev Mode you will see just raw value of buildNum variable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the accepted answer is wrong. First, it will fail on build-time because the date is not correctly formed.

This depends on how you build the app. In all cases, you should expose the env var like this ([docs on vite and .env](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode#env-files))

```
VITE_SENTRY_RELEASE_VERSION=something
```

Let's say you have the build script in the package.json like this

```json
scripts: {
  "build": "NODE_ENV=production svelte-kit sync && vite build",
}
```

and you use pnpm. The command would be

```
VITE_SENTRY_RELEASE_VERSION=something pnpm build
```

Now, in the code, you would reference it like this:

```
export const sentryRelease = import.meta.env.VITE_SENTRY_RELEASE_VERSION;
```

The value will be replaced with the correct env variable value.